# To show set equality $ (A\cup B)\cap C\neq A\cup(B\cap C) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to Show that

$$
(A\cup B)\cap C\neq A\cup(B\cap C);      
$$

but also give some special cases where there is equality .

Using the distributive property of set,i got
$$(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)\neq (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$ which shows that they are not equal.  As for the special case, I realized from both equations above that
$$(A\cap C)=A$$ and $$A\cup C = C$$ which means $$A\subset C$$ I don't know if this makes $$
(A\cup B)\cap C= A\cup(B\cap C);      
$$
If so , what other special cases makes them equal.

Comment: Compare the two venn diagrams [$(A\cup B)\cap C$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28A+or+B%29+and+C) and [$A\cup (B\cap C)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=A+or+%28B+and+C%29).  The two are equal iff the regions who are shaded in one but not the other contain no elements.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde no

Comment: You can use the counterexample from the duplicate to exclude many cases for equality, or think of similar counterexamples.

Comment: Thanks guys I understand it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see the figure to visualize it better, one of the statement is colored with red and the other one with blue.

As JMoravits said, if you want blue and red regions to be equal, you should have "the regions who are shaded in one but not the other contain no elements".

Which is the situation you described: A ⊂ C

There is no other special cases.

[venn diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73y9f.png)

Comment: Thanks, @hater . i have worked it out